# Laravel Storage returns: mkdir(): File exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-filesystem

When I'll try to check if a file exists in Laravel 5.1 I am always getting this error:

```
ErrorException in Local.php line 95: 
mkdir(): File exists
```

I don't know what could here be wrong, I want to check if a file exists or not with:

```
$exists = Storage::disk('images')->has('filename.jpg');

dd($exists);
```

Disk "images":

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path().'/app',
    ],

    'images' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path().'/app/images',
    ],
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure directory `storage_path().'/app/images'` exists? Does it has correct file permissions?

Comment: Yes it exists, and it worked already with a previous version (ill guess L5.0) - its strange - because i am unable to check ANY files with Storage::get(); - always getting the same error

Comment: What exact version do you use? Have you tried upgrading to last 5.1 version?

Comment: I am using the Version 5.1.27 (LTS) - already updated Laravel, but still bringing the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would try fresh installation to verify if you experience the same problem on fresh installation:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel testfiles 5.1.*
```

add into `filesystems.php` in `disks`:

```
'images' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path().'/app/images',
    ],
```

Modify in `Http/routes.php` file so root path looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $exists = Storage::disk('images')->has('filename.jpg');
    dd($exists);
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Of course you need to also set up domain for this sample project.

On mine PC I'm getting `false` without any error.

If you have this error on fresh install, well, it's a problem, if not, maybe you could also publish your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files to verify it on exact libarries you are using?

Comment: Thanks - ill done a fresh install and it worked. So deleted all the permissions for the User and tried again. And it works. So (i am not sure) but maybe it was really a file permission problem. The error is a little bit weird, because i know that there is a "Permission denied" error too. Thanks for pointing me into that direction!

Comment: i create folder by using generate current date, how can i applicated in filesystem.php